# Assign a value to a field on SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

im not sure if im doing well with this field **calendar.type_event = NULL**. Now works well to me because I need to differentiate the second SELECT as a third type.

I want to do something like **calendar.type_event = 'shared_event'** to differentiate it. But returns a 0, with NULL returns nothing. This is not the problem only I need to know if I can assign my own value: 'shared_event'.

Thanks a lot

The entire query is:

```
(SELECT     
    id, type_event
    FROM calendar
    WHERE user_id = '.$user_id.'        
)       

 UNION

(SELECT 
    calendar.id, calendar.type_event = NULL
    FROM calendar
    RIGHT JOIN avisos ON avisos.app_id = calendar.id 
    WHERE avisos.user_destiny_id = '.$user_id.'
)

ORDER BY fecha_evento ASC
```

Comment: What data type is `calendar.type_event`?

Comment: is a string, with two cases: 'notice' or 'event' and need to set to 'shared_event' on the fly

Comment: Okay, then check my answer below. It should work.

Comment: In no RDBMS I'm aware of does `<some reference> = null` return anything but `null` - this _includes_ `null = null` (this doesn't return `true` or `false` - you're essentially comparing two unknowns, so the system says "I have no way of knowing").  You can use `<reference> IS NULL`, but that's probably not what you want here.  Also, people tend to find `RIGHT JOIN`s difficult - the expectation is that whatever's in the `FROM` clause is always there.  I prefer to reverse the references and use a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I need to know if I can assign my own value: `'shared_event'`.*

Yes, you can. In place of column `calendar.type_event` just use literal `'shared_event'`

**Example**:

```
SELECT 
       calendar.id, 'shared_event'
  FROM calendar
       RIGHT JOIN avisos ON avisos.app_id = calendar.id 
 WHERE avisos.user_destiny_id = '.$user_id.'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
(SELECT     
    id, type_event
    FROM calendar
    WHERE user_id = '.$user_id.'        
)       

 UNION

(SELECT 
    calendar.id, "shared_event"
    FROM calendar
    RIGHT JOIN avisos ON avisos.app_id = calendar.id 
    WHERE avisos.user_destiny_id = '.$user_id.'
)

ORDER BY fecha_evento ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
(SELECT     
    id, type_event
    FROM calendar
    WHERE user_id = '.$user_id.'        
)       
UNION
(SELECT 
    calendar.id, '' type_event
    FROM calendar
    RIGHT JOIN avisos ON avisos.app_id = calendar.id 
    WHERE avisos.user_destiny_id = '.$user_id.'
)
ORDER BY fecha_evento ASC
```

In the second query, `type_event` field will contain null values. If the `type_event` field is a numeric field, you can put `0` (ZERO) instead of `''` (empty single quotes/string).

Comment: No, `null` is different conceptually than an empty string or a `0` amount (people are annoyed at Oracle for violating this, generally).  Using such 'flag' values leads to problems.  If it's supposed to be null (as in 'missing'), leave it as null - what happens if the value chosen here ends up being a valid value?

Comment: Also, the inital question requires the field `type_event` to be set to the string `shared_event` for the second select query in the union.

Comment: I intentionally kept the `type_event` as `''` because I thought @Theblabla just want to have the value 'shared_event' to identify other events found in the second query; and it looks like the first query WILL HAVE a value for the `type_event` field; so however empty string is given for `type_event`, shared events rows will be identifiable. I used empty string to minimize data production by the query and for a bit faster speed.